# Get encoding for xml-file using TBXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding, tbxml

How do I access the encoding for an xml-file using TBXML?

To clarify: I would like to acsess the top row in an xml-file and there get the value of encoding by using TBXML.

`?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, it's not part of the xml document.

Why do you want to know the encoding?

Comment: Because some files are using ISO-8859-1 encoding while others are using utf-8

Comment: But why do you need to care - surely the xml decoder will deal with that for you?

Comment: Because when I have a file that is using ISO-8859-1 and try to get the text for an element (using TBXML) that have letters like å, ä, ö I just get an empty string. If I change the encoding in the TBXML:class I can get it to work but then I get problems when I have an xml-file that is using UTF-8.

Comment: Hmm, Tricky. Assuming that you can't change the encoding of the xml yourself beforehand, take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268661/how-to-detect-text-file-encoding-in-objective-c - this should let you know the encoding. The other way is to read in the file in ASCII and parse it for 'encoding=...' but that's a nasty hack!

Comment: Managed to get to work by looking at the other question and using stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: Thanks!