# Hebrew Characters in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, character-encoding, hebrew

I have an app that downloads the html of a website the contains characters in hebrew, this is the code:

```
let newurl = NSURL(string: "http://www.handasaim.co.il")
var error: NSError?
let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: newurl!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)

if (error != nil) {
    println("Whoops, something went wrong")
} else {
    println(html)
}
```

My problem is that the hebrew characters show up as gibrish: *òøëú ùòåú - éåí ùéùé*

How can I download the html and get the correct characters?

Comment: Most probably, NSASCIIStringEncoding is *not* the correct encoding. Try NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: Or have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32051684/1187415 for a method to detect the encoding of the server response automatically.

Comment: NSUTF8StringEncoding is not working for me, and the response.textEncodingName doesn't return any value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This server's response encoding is "Windows Hebrew".

I'm using CoreFoundation to find the correct String encoding equivalent:

```
let newurl = NSURL(string: "http://www.handasaim.co.il")
var error: NSError?
let encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(UInt32(CFStringEncodings.WindowsHebrew.rawValue))
let html = String(contentsOfURL: newurl!, encoding: encoding, error: &error)
```

Result:

> תיכון להנדסאים הרצליה ליד אוניברסיטת תל אביב

**Swift 2 update**

```
if let newurl = NSURL(string: "http://www.handasaim.co.il") {
    let encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(UInt32(CFStringEncodings.WindowsHebrew.rawValue))
    if let html = try? String(contentsOfURL: newurl, encoding: encoding) {
        print(html)
    }
}
```

*Note: have a look at Martin R's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051684/1187415) to detect the encoding of the server response automatically. My method for this solution was to inspect the headers with curl.*