# Decode DAT file with Hebrew text

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, character-encoding

I have a `.DAT` file with Hebrew text, I want to decode the data. When trying to decode using text editors on Mac (BBEdit, Sublime or TextEdit) the Hebrew text becomes gibberish.

The file originally was in this format:

```
1081             310120     310120      197700  $ ‰˜…ˆ‰” .” .–…„ 01/20           01
```

And i've managed to change it to this format:

```
1081             310120     310120      197700  $ èâòÖàâî .î .ñÖÑ 01/20           01
```

When trying an online decoder: http://www.online-decoder.com/he it works and decode by default from `macCroatian` to `IBM862`, but there is no such encoding in Swift.

I found a library which I think that can help me do that, but can't add it to my project: https://www.example-code.com/swift3/load_text_file_using_code_page.asp

What is the best way to decode the .DAT file in Swift?

Comment: “I have a .DAT file with Hebrew text, I want to encode the data” Did you mean decode?

Comment: `'‰˜…ˆ‰” .” .–…„'.encode('cp1255').decode('cp862')` returns `'ירוטיפ .פ .צוה'`; however, I don't know whether it's meaningful Hebrew… Please add Hebrew equivalent to your [mcve]. (code given in Python)

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, sorry, I meant decode.

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you. Yes, the result that you've pasted is Hebrew. But didn't quite understand how to decode it using Swift...

Comment: I'd try [`init(contentsOfFile:encoding:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412610-init) Returns an NSString object initialized by reading data from the file at a given path using a given encoding. Related: [Hebrew Characters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521515/hebrew-characters-in-swift). Sorry, I don't understand :Swift_…

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730379/how-can-i-convert-a-string-such-as-iso-8859-1-to-its-string-encoding-counte) which helped me put out this code from first answer:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "somefile", ofType: "dat") {
    do {                
        let encoding = "cp862" // String encoding
        let converted = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encoding as CFString)
        let encoded = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(converted)
        let sEncoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: se)
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: sEncoding)
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
} else {
    // example.txt not found!
}
```