# NSURLSession does not returns data for http/https

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I need to get the data from the url it works for other url like udemy but **returns nil for url="http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=INR"** 
how to solve this issue. i have added app transport security too..

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaGR2.png)

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-ios-9-developer-course/")!

   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let url_content = data{
        let webcontent = NSString(data: url_content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(webcontent)
    }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: What's is nil exactly? What's the value of `data`, `error`, `webcontent`?

Comment: i just using url_content that stores data i need to get the whole html content to console,

Comment: @RohitPradhan i need html response only

Comment: @EricD. replace the udemy link with the google link that i given above and check

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a text encoding problem. The webpage at http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=INR is not encoded with `UTF-8` but with `ISO-8859-1`.

In this case, you have to use `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` for NSString:

```
let webcontent = NSString(data: url_content, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
```

Comment: I used `curl -I theURL` in the Terminal to check the response headers. But now I just remembered that Martin R already gave an answer about how to get the same info via Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32051684/2227743

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "error" variable to see if you have an error returned by the call. Most probably you have an error accessing that url.

Note that I tried the code and I could get data.

Comment: pls show me the code snippet that worked for u and how to check error returned by call by code help me to solve.