# How do I handle "special" characters (like section) in NSString

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsurl

In the code below, I have removed all other processing in the block.
I am getting an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."  The error occurs on the line

```
let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

I have determined that the problem is that there is a section symbol in the page.  A hex dump of `data` shows an A7 (so It's not an html tag).  If I remove the symbol from the page, the problem goes away.  (Unfortunately, I don't have control of the 'live' pages)

How do I keep this error from  happening?

```
let attemptedURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.ilnb.uscourts.gov/sites/all/ajax/calendar.php?mobile=true&judge=\(hearJudge)&start=\(hearDate)&print=true")
print(attemptedURL)

if let url = attemptedURL {

    // Create a task to run the web content through
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data {

            var contThis = true

            let webContent =  NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can stop the crash with `if let` but, since you already use that style of code elsewhere, I suspect that's not what you're asking.  What do you **want** to have happen when the encoding is wrong?

Comment: I want to be able to remove/change the offending character.  Can I change it in urlContent (using regex possibly) before I do the let webContent?

(Sorry, my experience is in other languages.  I'm just now learning Swift, and this is my first project)

Comment: I haven't done this but....  `NSData` has a `getBytes:length:` method that lets you read the underlying content into your own buffer.  You could make modifications there and then wrap the buffer in a new data object for converting to a string.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I will give that a try.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: The other question, of course, is: Is there a way to just get the NSString to accept the A7 character without crashing?

Comment: @EdGioja: A better approach could be to *detect* the web server's encoding and convert the data correspondingly, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/32051684/1187415.

Comment: The method assumes you're using a standard encoding of some kind.  If there's something else that the source conforms to, it might be an option you can specify.  (See `NSStringEncoding` in the docs for options.)

Comment: @EdGioja: Also note that A7 is the paragraph sign "§" in the Windows-1252 encoding, so NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding might be a good guess.

Comment: @MartinR: Reading the encoding from the page did not help, but the `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` did.  Thank you very much.