# Getting the Webpage HTML code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the html code of the webpage using following code :-

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")
var error: NSError?
let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

if (error != nil) {
    print("whoops, something went wrong")
} else {
    print(html!)
}
```

But i am getting following error in line number 3 ( let html = ....) :-

```
Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, encoding:, error:)' do not match any available overloads
```

Comment: `NSError` code management has changed in Swift. You have to make `do/catch`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `NSString(contentsOfURL url: NSURL, encoding enc: UInt) throws`

Your code should look like this:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com") {
    do {
        let html = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(html)
    } catch {
        print("whoops, something went wrong")
    }
}
```

For more information, take a look at the [new way of handling errors](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/error-handling-in-swift-2/) in Swift.

**UPDATE**

Used with your URL:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.police.gov.bd/career_child.php?id=247%20order%20by%201--") {
    do {
        let html = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(html)
    } catch {
        print("whoops, something went wrong")
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

To autodetect the encoding see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050969/why-my-return-is-nil-but-if-i-press-the-url-in-chrome-safari-i-can-get-data/32051684#32051684)

Comment: always executing catch, not executing do

Comment: @shubhammishra If I execute that code in playground, I get the html content printed. Make sure the URL you use is correct (and has the scheme prefix, such as `http://`or `https://`)

Comment: http://www.police.gov.bd/career_child.php?id=247%20order%20by%201--  this url works fine in browser but fails to do so using above

Comment: You have to use `http://www.police.gov.bd/career_child.php?id=247%20order%20by%201--`, without http it is not well formatted

Comment: yes that url is working fine, but please check for this url:http://www.corporatebpl.com/blog.php?show=250%20order%20by%201--

Comment: here also i have provided http:// and www. before the link but since it is in comment so it is not showing

Comment: that page has another type of encoding, use `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` encoding instead and it will work

Comment: so, how could i know which website has which kind of encoding ?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'UInt' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>' This error is comming in NSISOLatinStringEncoding

Comment: Because it is `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`, not `NSISOLatinStringEncoding`. When I use the code above with that encoding and your url it works fine. PS: I also added a new edit for autodetecting the encoding

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com") {
    do {
        let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    } catch {
        print("failure")
    }
}
```