# Can not convert umlauts (Ü Ö Ä ü ö ä è é) to .utf8

Tags: swift, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I want to decode response from the http request. But getting error while encoding to `.utf8`

`String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` returns `nil` when data contains umlauts from German language(Ü Ö Ä ü ö ä è é)

How can I decode the `Data?` object properly?

Edit:
Providing more details

This is how my response looks like. I can't change it's coming from backend similar to this.

```
let string = """
            {
            "test":"Value",
            "OperatingInfosQuotes":"\n<div id=\"div_operatinginfo_inner\">\n<div id=\"div_operatinginfo_title\"><b>Test</b></div>\n<div id=\"div_operatinginfo_content\">\n\n Ü Ö Ä ü ö ä è é\n\n</div>\n</div>\n"
            }
            """
    
do {
  let encode = try JSONDecoder().decode(TestObject.self, from: Data(string.utf8))
  print(encode)
} catch {
  print("Count not decode")
}
```

And my codable object:

```
struct TestObject: Codable {
    var test: String
}
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: That means that the HTTP response is not UTF-8 encoded but uses some different encoding.

Comment: Your `data` is probably in [`Win-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Try `encoding: .windowsCP1252`

Comment: You need to [edit] your question with some sample data, otherwise no one will be able to give you a definitive answer. If you UTF-8 encode those chars, they decode just fine. The problem most probably is that your data is not UTF-8 encoded, but that's impossible to tell without seeing your actual data.

Comment: You can also try to *detect* the encoding from the HTTP response, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051684/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encoding: .windowsCP1252` helped.

The issue was that Json contains quotes ("") and it breaks the format of Json in Swift and couldn't convert to `.utf8` as well.

If quotes will be removed from response everything will be okay, if not workaround is to convert to `.windowsCP1252` string.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is completely wrong.

A Swift string has no encoding, it's just a sequence of characters. Your data contains bytes, which are characters stored in some encoding. You *claim* that the encoding is UTF8 which is apparently wrong.

There are two possibilities: One is that you *know* the encoding of the data and pass the correct one. The other is that if you don't know the encoding, you use a different function where you don't need to specify the encoding; instead the OS will look at the decoding and decide what is most likely the correct encoding. The result will only be nil if it is *not* any encoding that iOS understands.

Comment: A Swift `String` *does* have an encoding: UTF-8. It it not *just* a sequence of `Character`, though you can interact with it as such. It is not like C strings. Any use of APIs which convert to or from other encodings are doing so from the base UTF-8 representation.